# Detectar cierre de pestaña Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

estoy desarrollando una web en la cual necesito ir saltando entre distintas pantallas, una vez que se cierre la pestaña en cualquier pantalla quiero que se acabe la sesión de dicho usuario.

Mi problema es que usando onbeforeunload, y añadiendo unas condiciones para que no se salga de la sesión mientras navego por las distintas pantallas que tiene mi web, funcionaría, pero si uso los botones del navegador de chrome de atrás/siguiente/refrescar, también se sale de la sesión.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que sólo se salga de la sesión cuando cierre la pestaña y no cuando dé a los botones de atrás/siguiente/refrescar?

De esta forma controlo cuándo debería cerrarse la sesión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]